# Was Colin Kaepernick listed for sale on Amazon after the November 1st, 2015 loss?

Tags: sport, amazon

The news cycle ([here](http://www.rollingstone.com/sports/news/colin-kaepernick-hits-rock-bottom-after-being-put-up-for-sale-on-amazon-20151103), [here](http://www.foxsports.com/nfl/story/san-francisco-49ers-colin-kapernick-for-sale-on-amazon-110115)) has been reporting that Colin Kaepernick, (benched) quarterback for the San Francisco 49ers, was listed for sale on Amazon after the 27-6 loss to the St. Louis Rams on November 1st, 2015. However, the image they've been floating (below) has an Amazon tag that asks whether the purchaser wants it by September 15.

So this brings up two questions. (1) Did Colin Kaepernick ever get posted for sale on Amazon, and (2) if so, when did this occur?

[image]

Comment: No he wasn't. Images like there  were created by this blogger http://www.mandatory.com/2015/09/24/amazon-reviews-of-nfl-quarterbacks/

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub: That looks like an answer. Would you like to use the answer box, please?

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub If you throw this into an answer it will be a fairly immediate acceptance.

Comment: @SocioMatt, okay will do today. There are other indications as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is an image has been created by blogger [Christopher Hudspeth](http://www.mandatory.com/bloggers/christopher-hudspeth) on September 24, 2015, as he published on his blog post titled [AMAZON REVIEWS OF NFL QUARTERBACKS](http://www.mandatory.com/2015/09/24/amazon-reviews-of-nfl-quarterbacks/) where he said:

> So what if fans were able to review their team's quarterback's performance the same way we do with a lamp, a Kindle, a cell phone case, or whatever random items you purchase on Amazon. **I reckon it would look a little something like this.**

The image was accompanied with other images as well:

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]

It is good to mention that on [Hudspeth's](https://twitter.com/CEHudspeth) twitter account, [he explicitly said they were "pretend Amazon reviews"](https://twitter.com/CEHudspeth/status/647147025809608708):

[image]